# CDF of probability from a ClassifierFunction

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, machine-learning

I have a classifier function that classifies whether a student is likely to succeed in a course given their score on a placement test. From this, I am pulling both the probability of being successful and being unsuccessful. For example,

```
classifyReading[{80, "RDG-098"}, "Probabilities"]
```

and the output is

```
<|"successful" -> 0.762894, "unsuccessful" -> 0.237106|>
```

But instead of calculating the probability that a student with a grade of 80 will succeed, I need to calculate the probability that a student with a grade <=80 will succeed. I feel like I'm missing something here that should be simple.

Comment: Integrate the results for grades $0 \to 80$.

Comment: @DavidGStork It doesn't work by integrating (for no other reason than an integration would most likely result in a value much larger than 1).

Comment: Given the analysis already performed, you could list the range of probabilities associated grades of less than or equal to 80.  Alternatively, you could perform another analysis that just uses a variable that takes on just two values depending on grade: <= 80 and > 80.